# Убрать выделение первой ячейки в DataGridView

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, нашёл вот такой код для запрета в DataGridView использования символов кроме цифр и запятых.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)e.Control;
            tb.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(tb_KeyPress);
        }
    }
    void tb_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!((e.KeyChar >= (char)48 && e.KeyChar <= (char)57) || (e.KeyChar == (char)8) || (e.KeyChar == (char)45) || (e.KeyChar == (char)44)))
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Но возникла проблема с первой ячейкой в таблице, которая автоматически выделяется при запуске программы и событие не срабатывает для неё, пока не выберешь другую ячейку. Вопрос: Как сделать, чтобы при запуске не выделялась первая ячейка, либо как сделать чтобы событие выполнялось сразу после запуска.

Comment: При открытии формы программно выдели вторую ячейку.

Comment: this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView1[1,0];
this.dataGridView1.ClearSelection();

такой костыль помог убрать начальное выделение, но при выделении первой ячейки событие все равно не срабатывает и можно записать буквы в ячейку

А если сделать так
this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView1[1,0];
то он выделит вторую ячейку и событие сработает, не пойму логику

Comment: Нашел решение! if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1) необходимо поставить 0 вместо 1 и он будет работать начиная с 1 столбца.